# How to implement our own UID in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I wish to create an index with, lets say the following fields :
`UID

 title

 owner

 content`

out of which, I don't want UID to be searchable. [ like meta data ]
I want the UID to behave like docID so that when I want to delete or update, 
I'll use this.
Is this possible ? How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mark is as non-searchable by adding it with `Store.YES` and `Index.NO`, but that wont allow you easy updating/removal by using it. You'll need to index the field to allow replacing it (using `IndexWriter.UpdateDocument(Term, Document)` where term = `new Term("UID", "...")`), so you need to use either `Index.ANALYZED` with a `KeywordAnalyzer`, or `Index.NOT_ANALYZED`. You can also use the `FieldCache` if you have a single-valued field, which a primary key usually is. However, this makes it searchable.

Summary:

- `Store.NO` (It can be retrieved using the `FieldCache` or a `TermsEnum`)
- `Index.NOT_ANALYZED` (The complete value will be indexed as a term, including any whitespaces)

Comment: so it is either I make it searchable or loose the update/delete functionality right ? No way to get 2 birds with one hit ?

Comment: You need it to be searchable to be able to find it when you need to remove it (update is really remove + insert). You could just have it stored, non-searchable, but then you need to iterate all documents to find which one has the stored uid you're looking for.